# Software to turn my Android phone into a security camera with an offline option?

Tags: android, camera, remote-control, android-nougat, video-surveillance

Looking for recommendations for an Android app (I'm running Android 7.0 Nougat) that will let me use my phone as a remote camera.

I would like to have as many of the following as possible:

- (essential) Ability to record video to local storage without using any networks (wifi/cellular/bluetooth/nothing)
- (optional) Ability to store video on a "loop," i.e. storing up to x hours and thereafter deleting the oldest bit of footage as new footage is recorded
- (optional) Ability to detect motion and start/stop recording based on presence/absence of motion
- (optional) Ability to remotely monitor in real time
- (optional) Ability to turn flash on/off in real time

Comment: You may wish to check [these candidates](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_webcams#group_729) (disclosure: link goes to my website).